# How can I restore my "likes" tab?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-like

On my Facebook page, I accidentally hid my “Likes” tab, so now neither I nor my friends can see my likes.

Earlier, in my profile, when I clicked the *More* option, the option of seeing my likes appeared, and by mistake, I clicked **Hide section** so now I cannot see my likes regarding general subjects but can see the likes related to Movies, Books, Music.

Answer (score 3):

To unhide the “Likes” tab on your Facebook page:

1. Go to the top of the page and look for *About*;
2. Click on the picture of the pen on the far right;
3. Click **Edit Sections**;
4. Check the sections that you want showing on your *About* page (ex: Likes, Movies, Music, TV, Books);
5. Click **Save**.